# Ruby: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=unknown state (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

Tags: ruby, openssl

Variants of this error have been posted all over the place but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

I'm running `ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]` and
`OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015`.

Running the following:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'

url = 'https://ntpnow.com/'
uri   = URI.parse(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.ssl_version = :TLSv1
http.get(uri.path)
```

Dumps this trace:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect': SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=unknown state (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `block in connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:74:in `timeout'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1133:in `get'
    from bin/ntpnow_test.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

Navigating to the site from a browser shows the certificate appears to be fine.  Curl also does not produce any errors.

Additionally, when I try with Ruby 1.9.3 it seems to work.  However, I'm not inclined to downgrade Ruby versions if I can find a solution.

Can you please tell me what exactly changed that is causing this problem?

UPDATE:

Steffen's answer and explanation below is correct.  For future reference, here is how to diagnose this problem.

1. First determine which ciphers the server supports.  Run the command `nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers ntpnow.com`.  Find the section that lists the supported ciphers.
2. Determine the cipher key you will have to pass as part of `http.ciphers`.  Run  `openssl ciphers`.  This will spit out a `:` delimited list of ciphers.  Find the one that matches the result from step 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks like exactly the same problem I've answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29611892/3081018. Same problem: the server can only do TLS 1.0 and only supports DES-CBC3-SHA as cipher. This cipher is no longer enabled by default in recent ruby versions. To connect with this cipher try to specify the cipher explicitly in your code:

```
http.ssl_version = :TLSv1
http.ciphers = ['DES-CBC3-SHA']
```

Comment: Excellent! This worked.  The only difference is that I had to use DES-CBC3-SHA as the cipher.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @prajo: I've changed the answer to use the correct cipher.

Comment: Using enqryption to be secure, but instead we need to use a fundamentally broken enqryption :(

Answer (score 3):

I use Mechanize, and I was looking for a patch instead of a configuration of the http client instance. This is how I managed to do it:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:ciphers] += ':DES-CBC3-SHA'
```

Comment: You can add it in an initializer (e.g. when using Rails) or you can call it just before executing your script