# Puppet 4.3.2 client node unable to connect via SSL to Puppet Server

Tags: ruby, apache, ssl, puppet

I have just done a clean regeneration of all my Puppet certifications as per [the guide in the official docs](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.3/reference/ssl_regenerate_certificates.html).

However, I encounter this error with seemingly no good leads on Google, SO, nor anywhere else.

```
[vagrant@client puppet]$ hostname
client.example.com

[vagrant@client puppet]$ puppet --version
4.3.2

[vagrant@client puppet]$ sudo puppet config print vardir ssldir
vardir = /var/opt/puppetlabs/puppetserver
ssldir = /var/opt/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ssl

[vagrant@client puppet]$ sudo puppet agent --test --server=puppet.example.com
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=unknown state
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Error: /File[/var/opt/puppetlabs/puppetserver/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect
Error: /File[/var/opt/puppetlabs/puppetserver/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///pluginfacts: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=unknown state
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/var/opt/puppetlabs/puppetserver/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=unknown state
Error: /File[/var/opt/puppetlabs/puppetserver/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///plugins: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=unknown state
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=unknown state
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=unknown state
```

This [is a similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572956/ruby-ssl-connect-syscall-returned-5-errno-0-state-unknown-state-opensslssl), but for general SSL in Ruby, and I'm not sure how to change the cipher for Puppet (don't think it is enabled).

[This post seems to suggest it may be Apache's fault](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/puppet-users/5CmY1ZBEHVE), but I don't think I'm using Apache.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using puppetserver (in your example, in `puppet.example.com`?). If you're not, you might actually be using Apache.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Puppet Server as opposed to the older Puppet Master. How would I fix that in that case?

Comment: If it's indeed a cipher problem. check if you're using a recent version of Java and the configuration of the JCA provider (and if the JCA uses a native library, if this is updated as well). If in doubt download the latest Java 8 distribution from Oracle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same problem.

Check your ssl directory on the agent with the command:

```
sudo puppet config print ssldir
```

Your ssl directory is probably not in /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl, but probably under /opt/puppetlabs. Remove your certificate (or the entire catalog) from this directory and then perform another puppet run.

Comment: The solution was a mismatch in configuration locations - settings for the ssldir and vardir should not be made in [main] - setting appropriate values in the [user] and [master] sections did the trick. So while your solution wasn't technically correct, I'll give you the points since they'll otherwise go to waste.